# Transpose groups of columns to rows

Tags: r, transpose

I have a large dataset with more than 600 columns. an extract looks like this:

```
  category q151_a34 q151_a35 q151_a36 q151_a37 q152_a34 q152_a35 q152_a36 q152_a37
1 men      2         12      37       24       0        7        19       23
2 women    3         10      23       19       2        4        29       16
```

Now I want to convert/transpose it to the following structure:

```
  category  var     a34 a35 a36 a37
1 men       q151    2   12   37  24
2 men       q152    0   7    19  23
3 women     q151    3   10   23  19
4 women     q152    2   4    29  16
```

I found a two step solution:
*step 1*: spliting variables

```
get.first<- function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, "\\_"), `[[`, 1)
data<- within(data, var<- get.first(as.character(variable)))
get.second <- function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, "\\_"), `[[`, 2)
data<- within(data, answer<- get.first(as.character(variable)))
```

*step 2*: transposing

```
freqTest <- dcast(data, category + var~ idAnswer, value.var = "value")
```

Is there a nicer/more performant way?

Many thanks

Comment: More tags? What programming language is this? How will people knowledgeable in that language easily find your question: most of them are probably not following the `transpose` tag.

Comment: you are right, its related to "r", thanks for indicating!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`tidyr`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/) from the [`tidyverse`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/) group of packages for this:

```
# install.packages('tidyverse')


library(tidyverse)

# Data

dff <- structure(list(category = structure(1:2, .Label = c("men", "women" ), class = "factor"), q151_a34 = 2:3, q151_a35 = c(12L, 10L), 
    q151_a36 = c(37L, 23L), q151_a37 = c(24L, 19L), q152_a34 = c(0L, 
    2L), q152_a35 = c(7L, 4L), q152_a36 = c(19L, 29L), q152_a37 = c(23L, 
    16L)), .Names = c("category", "q151_a34", "q151_a35", "q151_a36",  "q151_a37", "q152_a34", "q152_a35", "q152_a36", "q152_a37"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

# Code

gather(dff, key=Qs, value = values, q151_a34:q152_a37) %>%
    separate(Qs, into = c('var','A')) %>%
    spread(A, values)


# Output

  category  var a34 a35 a36 a37
1      men q151   2  12  37  24
2      men q152   0   7  19  23
3    women q151   3  10  23  19
4    women q152   2   4  29  16
```

Essentially, you first need to move the column names into rows with the help of the `gather` function, and then use the `separate` function to separate the values by the underscore. This will put both values starting with `q` in one column while putting those values starting with `a` in another column. From here, the next step is to put back the values starting with `a` as your column names, with the help of the `spread` function. Combined, these steps should get to your desired output.

#### Edit:

If you don't want to deal with getting the names of the columns you are looking to move into rows, then you can try using the following:

```
gather(dff, key=Qs, value = values, -category) %>%
    separate(Qs, into = c('var','A')) %>%
    spread(A, values)
```

This is exactly the same as the previous solution, with the only difference being that you are only concerning yourself with the column you wish to have remain a column. Essentially, this brings down everything but the column name `category`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: very interesting and a strong help. One point I will have to look at is the naming of the column names, as in your solution they have to be included in the code (cfr q151_a34:q152_a37).